# Rails 2.2.2 : quick testing of routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Whenever i have a routing bug i always end up going through a cycle of "change config/routes.rb, reload page, watch log file to see which controller/action is called".  It's quite slow, as the app in question is very large and loading the environment (which is done on each request in dev mode) takes a significant time.

Does anyone know a way to just query the router alone, eg call the router with a url and get a hash of controller, action & params back, without having to load my entire app every time?

This is for a rails 2.2.2 app btw.  (Yes i know i should update, not an option atm unfortunately)

Comment: `rake routes` should work on 2.2.2.

Comment: `rake routes` does work, but it's not quite what i'm after.  `rake routes` is like a program or a formula, i'm after the results of running the program/formula with a specific input, if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Action Controller routing assertions:

`actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions/routing_assertions.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this: the key was `ActionController::Routing::Routes` which returns the built routes map, and the `recognize_path` method called on this.

```
def test_route(url, method = :get)
  method = method.to_s.downcase.to_sym
  uri = Addressable::URI.parse(CGI.unescape(url))
  path = uri.path
  params = uri.query_values || {}
  routes = ActionController::Routing::Routes;false
  begin
    routes_hash = routes.recognize_path(path, {:method => method})
    HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(routes_hash.merge(params))
  rescue ActionController::RoutingError
    return nil
  rescue Exception => e
    raise $!
  end
end
```

if the routes map can't resolve a route it will raise an `ActionController::RoutingError` exception, and i catch this and return nil, to signify that no matching route was found.  Any other exceptions just get bounced up.